# Getting notified about clipboard content changes

Tags: x11, gnome, clipboard

I would like to watch clipboard in a way similar to how `inotify` watches files so I that I can display actual clipboard content in tmux status line or in any other custom GUI in my system. I don't like polling because it loads system and is not quite responsive. I am on GNOME/X11. Which ways do exist?

Answer (score 0):

Since this has gone so long without an answer, I'll take a flail at it.

First, polling would be easy, but you said you don't want to do that.

Find out what program provides your actual clipboard, kill it and then run it with strace and do a few simple clipboard actions and see what it does. Hopefully, this will give you some clues as to how and where it is storing the new data. Once you know that, then you'll know specifically what you're trying to detect.

Comment: I understand that I can create a small tool that listens X11 events and provides functionality; but I don't have spare time to learn X11 API or its bindings and was hoping that ready to use solution already exists

Answer (score 0):

[Clipnotify](https://github.com/cdown/clipnotify) is a simple program that responds when any change in the clipboard in detected.

PS. It monitors PRIMARY clipboard events (text selections) as well which might not be desired.. this is easily circumvented by simply commenting out the one line:-

`XFixesSelectSelectionInput(disp, root, XA_PRIMARY, XFixesSetSelectionOwnerNotifyMask);`

in the source code file `clipnotify.c` (All credits to a comment in [another stackexchange answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1167129/1384914) made by a user named [Akhil](https://askubuntu.com/users/835941/akhil) for suggesting this workaround.. it saved me a lot of trouble)

PS. to install clipnotify, simply clone the github repo and run the command `make` in the cloned directory. A new executable file will be created in the directory which is to be run to execute the program.